# Creating a column in a pandas dataframe conditional on dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I currently have a dataframe of customers, contracts, and contract dates like this ex

```
Cust  Contract  Start         End                  
   A   123      10/1/2021     11/3/2021  
   B   987      7/4/2022      8/12/2022
```

For each row, I want to generate a variable that tells me if it was active during a set range ex: 10/1/2021-12/31/2021.

When I import from the excel file, the 'Start' and 'End' Columns come in as datetime64[ns]

Code I have tried so far is this:

```
df.loc[df['Start'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')<='2021-10-31' & df['End'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')<='2021-10-1', 'Active Flag'] = 'Yes'
```

When I run this I get the following error

```
Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

I'm not really sure if I am even on the correct track for solving this, or if there is an easier way. Any help would be appreciated as Python's date time operations are very odd to me.

Comment: What about partial overlaps, e.g. the start OR the end for a row are within the `10/1/2021-12/31/2021` range, but not BOTH?

Comment: It has to be both for my purposes. I don't want contracts only active partially during any given period.

Comment: Is it just one dataframes? Or are you comparing two dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use simple date comparisons to solve this.

There could be two scenarios for these contracts :

1. Where the contract is ONLY active within the range

```
start_range = pd.to_datetime('10/1/2021') 
end_range = pd.to_datetime('31/12/2021')
#                                 --- Start Date ---         --- End Date --- 
df['Active_Only_in_Range'] = (df.Start >= start_range) & (df.End <= end_range) 
df['Active_Only_in_Range_Flag'] = np.where(df.Active_Only_in_Range,'Yes','No')
```

2. Where the contract was PARTIALLY active within the range (hence it started in the range or ended in the range - hence it has been partially active in the provided range)

```
start_range = pd.to_datetime('10/1/2021')
end_range = pd.to_datetime('31/12/2021')
#                       ----------- Start Date ------------                     ----------- End Date ------------
df['Partial_Active'] = ((df.Start >= start_range) & (df.Start <= end_range)) | ((df.End >= start_range) & (df.End <= end_range))
df['Partial_Active_Flag'] = np.where(df.Partial_Active,'Yes','No')
```

Thus, depending upon your problem you can find which one suits you.

Comment: My problem aligns with the first and that solution worked perfectly thanks!

Comment: @Tyler If it helps, could you please mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
# Convert to `datetime` first
df.Start = pd.to_datetime(df.Start, format="%m/%d/%Y") 
df.End = pd.to_datetime(df.End, format="%m/%d/%Y")

target = pd.date_range('2021-10-1', '2021-12-31')
df['is_active'] = df.Start.isin(target) | df.End.isin(target)
```

Output:

```
Out[17]: 
  Cust  Contract      Start        End  is_active
0    A       123 2021-10-01 2021-11-03       True
1    B       987 2022-07-04 2022-08-12      False
```